# Poisson distribution where each event can lead to different outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to tackle the following problem.

> Suppose that customers arriving at a bank follow a Poisson
>   distribution with rate λ=5 every 15 minutes. For every customer, the
>   probability that he performs one transaction is 0.4, two transactions
>   0.3, three transactions 0.2 and four transactions 0.1. Find the expected value and the variance of the number of transactions that
>   will be performed in a 3 hour interval.

My starting point was to calculate that, per customer the expected value of transactions is $0.4\cdot1+0.3\cdot2+0.2\cdot3+0.1\cdot4=2$

Additionally, if X is the number of customers in a 3 hour interval, $X \sim \operatorname{Pois} \left({5\cdot12}\right)$. So the expected value is 60 customers in 3 hours, in other words 120 transactions in 3 hours. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to calculate the variance of the number of transactions. Does the number of transactions in 3 hours also follow the Poisson distribution or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it does follow the poisson distribution as well, in which case the variance is the same as the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $X$ as the random number of customers arriving in a 3 hour interval, so $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 60)$ as you noted.  Now, for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, X$, let $T_i$ be the number of transactions that the $i^{\rm th}$ customer to arrive makes, so that $$\Pr[T_i = k] = 0.1 (5 - k), \quad k = 1, 2, 3, 4.$$  We can now calculate $$\operatorname{E}[T_i] = \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{k(5-k)}{10} = 2, \quad \operatorname{E}[T_i^2] = \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{k^2(5-k)}{10} = 5,$$ so that $\operatorname{Var}[T_i] = 5-2^2 = 1$.  Now we let $$S = \sum_{i=1}^X T_i$$ be the total number of transactions observed in the 3 hour interval.  We wish to compute $\operatorname{E}[S]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[S]$.  To this end, observe that

$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[S] &= \operatorname{E}_X[\operatorname{E}[S \mid X]] \\[8pt]
&= \operatorname{E}_X\left[\sum_{i=1}^X \operatorname{E}[T_i]\right] \\[8pt]
&= \operatorname{E}[X \operatorname{E}[T_i]] \\[8pt]
&= \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[T_i] \\[8pt]
&= 2\lambda = 120. \end{align*}$$

This is the law of total expectation.  Next, we use the law of total variance:

$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}[S] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[S \mid X]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[S \mid X]] \\[8pt] &\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{E}[X \operatorname{Var}[T_i]] + \operatorname{Var}[X \operatorname{E}[T_i]] \\[8pt]
&= \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{Var}[T_i] + \operatorname{E}[T_i]^2 \operatorname{Var}[X]. \end{align*}$$

Now it is a simple matter to recall that $\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{Var}[X] = \lambda$ for a Poisson distribution, and substitute the expectation and variance for $T_i$ that we computed above.  Note that this last formula $$\operatorname{Var}[S] = \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{Var}[T_i] + \operatorname{E}[T_i]^2 \operatorname{Var}[X]$$ applies to **any** random variable $S = T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_X$ where all the $T_i$s are iid, and $X$ is a nonnegative integer-valued random variable.  This formula is frequently found in actuarial contexts.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.

Comment: how is 5 - 2^2 = 4?

Comment: @user585380 That was a typographical error, which has been fixed.

Comment: @heropup could you look at this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002756/poisson-process-pizza-orders-2-types-over-period-of-time?rq=1

Comment: I up-voted this answer, but I have this qualm about it: This practice of using a random variable as a subscript on the expectation operator is nonsense. It should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the number of transactions in a 3 hour interval, $X$ the number of customers in a 3 hour interval (which is $\sim poisson(60)$ as you found), and $N$ the number of transactions per customer (which has expectation 2 as you say and variance 5 as you can verify). Then we have that $T=\sum_{i=1}^X N$. I personally used the conditional variance formula from here, which is a straightforward calculation after this setup.